# Copy Selected File in SharePoint To Local Drive

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to copy a selected from from a SharePoint Document List to the servers local drive. But I can not for the life of me find a way to do this within SharePoint 2010 using C# or JavaScript (preferably C#) anywhere. Is this possible? If it is, can anyone provide some pointers that would get me started in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You can use [Copy Service](http://tipsforsharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/download-file-using-sharepoint-copy-web.html) or client object model, or create your own custom wcf service for that using server object model. What have you tried. Have you got stuck with your code?

Comment: So far all i've done is created a Application page and deployed it to a Farm setup of SharePoint. But I have no idea how to get the selected item in the document list to the application page i created.

Comment: How is that related to copying a file?

Comment: I thought I could pass the file ID to the application page and then use C# to copy that file. I take it that is the wrong approach? I've never done this so I'm just guessing on how to do it. Any recommendation would be great. Oh and I would like to launch the code from the ribbon.

Comment: If you want to do it from the sharepoint page's ribbon. what do you mean by "servers local drive" in your question? what do you mean by server? And What do you mean by file - is it one of the word or any document stored in your sharepoint library?

Comment: Yea it could be a Word document, pdf, document, etc. More then likely a Word doc. By server local drive. I mean like a local folder, such as C:\WordDocs within windows on the SharePoint server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom actions to integrate the functionnality to ribbon ([see this article](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing.html)).

Once you have added your custom action in the code you can:

If you know a file server relative URL you can get it from the web

```
SPFile file = YourWebObject.GetFile("FileServerRelativeUrl");
```

Ones you have your SPFile object you can save it, using .NET IO library, to a disk using

```
FileStream fileStreamToSave = YourWebObject.OpenBinaryStream();
```

Than just save it...

**IMPORTANT!** - You have to give writ access to the folder where you files will be stored.